# is this good implementation of Multithreaded Caching in .Net?

Tags: .net, winforms, caching

While implementing Multithreaded Cache, i found this article on MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx

This is for windows appliation using framework 4.0. My main concern is Thread Safety. Currently i am using MemoryCache and i know it is not Thread Safe. So is the provided implementation a better way to implement Multithreaded Caching?

Please advice.

Comment: Did you forget to post your own code? Or a question with regards to the ReaderWriterLockSlim, which simply provides a means for implementing synchronization that _would_ be convenient for a mutlithreaded cache to use.

Comment: you should post some code here if you expect an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite see the relation between a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` and caching. This class is used to synchronize the access to a shared resource in a multithreaded application. For implementing data caching I would recommend you taking a look at the [System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx) namespace.

Comment: There is no relation but i just liked the implementation of that class. It looks very thread safe.

Comment: @Asdfg, as I said in my answer this class is used to synchronize the access to a shared resource from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently i am using MemoryCache and i know it is not Thread Safe.

MemoryCache is thread-safe - look at the Thread Safety section in [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx).

Of course the items you put into MemoryCache may not be thread-safe, which is another story.  In many cases MemoryCache is used to store immutable elements, which will be thread-safe.